# JavaScript unchek checkbox with dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a problem with unchecking checkbox with dynamic id.

Both of them are checked but I need to set if one is clicked that other one is disabled then
this is example:

```
<input id="value_Ture_do_30_15_0" class="rnr-checkbox" name="value_Ture_do_30_15[]" value="1" checked="checked" type="checkbox">

<input id="value_Ture_preko_30_15_0" class="rnr-checkbox" name="value_Ture_preko_30_15[]" value="1" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
```

I have tried this like:

```
$("[id^='value_Ture_do_30']").checked = false
```

Also this:

```
$(function () {
    $("[id^='value_Ture_do_30']).click(function (event) {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            $("[id^='value_Ture_preko_30']").find('input').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
    $("[id^='value_Ture_preko_30']").click(function (event) {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            $("[id^='value_Ture_do_30']").find('input').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
});
```

Also this solution did not work for me:
[Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/checking-a-checkbox-with-jquery)
But it does not work.
If you can help me
Thanks

Solved it like this:

```
$("[id^='value_Ture']").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this), 
        wasChecked = $this.attr("checked") === "checked";
    $("[id^='value_Ture']:checked").removeAttr("checked");
    if (wasChecked) {
        $this.attr("checked", "checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: `$("[id^='value_Ture_do']")[0].checked = false`

Comment: I don't think OP only needs to check checkboxes!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `prop()`

```
$("[id^='value_Ture_do_30']").prop('checked', false);
```

**SUGGESTION**

Why not using radios?

Comment: HI, still does not work, I need to use them